# Is there a way to pass multiple parameters in routing url in angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
app-routing.module.ts
{ path: 'projectmodel/:projectmodelname/salespack', component: componentname}
```

So here I want to be the url like this while navigating(on click on button i want to navigate to this page)
I tried like this

```
  this.router.navigate(['/projectmodel', this.salesPackName, '/salespack'])
this.salesPackName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('projectmodelname');
```

but it is giving page not found i.e i have given the wrong url. Where am i missing? I am new to angular. Any help it would be helful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need the slashes.

Have you tied:

```js
  this.router.navigate(['projectmodel', this.salesPackName, 'salespack'])
```